# Grails and Spring Security: license/usage agreement support

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've got a webapp which is using Grails with Spring Security plugin for it's authentication and authorisation.

I have a new requirement from the business that they want to force all users upon login to the system, to be displayed our current license agreement or t&cs, the user needs to accept these before being allowed further into the system.

Clearly, once they accept the license/t&cs, then we don't ask them again on future logins.

Does Spring Security support this in any way? Or can you recommend another grails plugin?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to add a new field to your User class (e.g. hasAcceptedLicense), redirect the user to a defaultUrl at login (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) where they need to read and accept a license, and then have a AccessDecisionVoter (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#voters) that makes sure they did so.